# Configure phpgrid with firebird

Tags: php, datagrid, firebird

How can I configure phpgrid to connect with firebird database?

I have to edit the conf.php file, but don't know how to configure it for Firebird..

Answer (score 5):

try this:

I would build and test a ODBC connection for the firebird database (for windows have a look at this site to get an idea: http://web.synametrics.com/firebird.htm).

the conf.php file would be something like this:

```
define('PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME','hostname'); // hostname = your odbc connection name
define('PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME', 'username'); // database user name
define('PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD', 'password'); // database password
define('PHPGRID_DB_NAME', 'sampledb'); // database name
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'odbc'); // database type = odbc for "generic odbc" or try ibase
define('PHPGRID_DB_CHARSET','utf8'); // OPTIONAL. Leave blank to use the default charset
```

Answer (score -1):

If you try using this [php datagrid library](http://www.phpgrid.org/support-firebird-sqlite-databases/), it use PDO and connect smoothly with firebird.

Working demo code: https://www.gridphp.com/demo/demos/loading/db-layer-firebird.phps

Comment: Wow, the answer came 4 years late